# iOS Today Widget show more compact mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios10, today-extension

I'm trying to show the today widget, with the button to Show more, but in iOS 10 I have only found info to show the button to Show More/less if I put the `NCWidgetDisplayMode` to Expanded. But then, the today widget is show expanded, and I would like it Compacted for the first time.

If I put the `NCWidgetDisplayMode` to Compact, then the Show more button disappears!

I have some apps that the behavior of the widget it's as I would like: the first time you set the widget, it's shown in compact mode, and with the button to Show more.

How can I archive this result? I have fond nothing that explains how to do it.

Comment: Call:  `requestPresentationStyle(.compact)`

Comment: Hi @shallowThought, do you know how I can call requestPresentationStyle in xamarin iOS? I did not found this property, in xamarin or Google.

Comment: No idea about Xamarin.  requestPresentationStyle() is a method, no property.

Comment: Thanks @shallowThought but to use this method, I have to inherit from MsMessagesAppViewController instead of UIViewController, and then the widget stops working. I will have to search for another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
   override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
    }
```

Now implement `NCWidgetProviding` protocol delegate method:

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize)
{
    if activeDisplayMode == .expanded
    {
        preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 200.0) //Size of the widget you want to show in expanded mode
    }
    else
    {
        preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
}
```

For more on how widgets work in **iOS8/iOS9/iOS10** you can refer to: https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget